# Internal Server Error al ejecutar MPDF y Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: php, mpdf, ubuntu-server

En mi servidor con `Ubuntu 18.04` le falla no poder usar normalmente el `file_get_contents`, siempre que se intenta usar, retorna un Internal Server Error. Para hacer que funcione, siempre tengo que agregarle unos parámetros adicionales para que funcione y no dé este error.

Ejemplo de cómo funcionaría un `file_get_contents` en mi servidor:

```
$opts = array('https'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$metas = file_get_contents('https://www.pagina.com/metas/home.php',false,$context);
```

El detalle es que estoy usando `MPDF`, y creo que no es correcto modificar el core de la librería, además, al convivir con este detalle de mi servidor y no poder usar `file_get_contents`, mi servidor me retorna un Internal Server Error ya que MPDF ocupa en ciertas partes de su core esta función de php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> No es mi código la imagen de arriba, es el código fuente de la librería MPDF, es solo como referencia para mostrar que la librería ocupa en su core la función de file_get_contents

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de poder solucionar este error o a alguno de ustedes ha experimentado algo así.

Adicional, dejo mi log de apache, para saber si puede ser de ayuda:

```
[Wed Jan 29 14:05:03.711895 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 2786 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:06:15.782651 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 2785 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:09:30.302403 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 2784 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:09:30.302529 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 2776 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:10:51.027410 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 4053 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:10:51.027523 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 4196 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:11:39.079388 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 4262 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Jan 29 14:11:39.079458 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 2755] mod_fcgid: process 4263 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Fernando. Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto para que sea más fácil verlo, leerlo y probarlo.

Comment: Hola, @Alfabravo Lo que pasa es que no es mi código, es el código fuente de la librería MPDF y la imagen es solo como referencia para mostrar que la librería ocupa en su core la función de file_get_contents

Comment: Dices que `... siempre tengo que agregarle unos parámetros adicionales para que funcione`. Creo que deberías indicar que parámetros extra son los que necesitas, para comenzar a buscar a partir de ahí.

Comment: Hola, @Trauma Gracias por tu respuesta. Me pareció irrelevante, sin embargo, ya actualicé mi pregunta para poder mostrar los parámetros adicionales que tengo que ocupar en orden de que funcione el file_get_contents.

Comment: Hola a todos, sigo debuggeando mi código y creo que se puede deber a la versión de mpdf que ocupo. El método que me está generando conflicto es WriteFixedPosHTML, sigo investigando y si lo logro solucionar volveré aquí con una respuesta. Estoy ocupando PHP 7.2

Comment: No veo que `file_get_contents( )` no funcione. Por lo que dices, y el código original de `mpdf`, me parece que, simplemente, `mpdf` **no soporta archivos no-locales**, y tu estas intentando que acceda a un archivo remoto.

Comment: El problema esta en mi servidor que no podía resolverse así mismo. Agregué los DNS de google a /etc/resolv.conf y también mi ip privada del servidor esatba mal y la cuadré a la que era y ahora ya se resuelve mi servidor a la misma ip usando curl o file_get_contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por sus comentarios en mi publicación con la intención de ayudarme. Al final encontré la raíz del problema: La IP privada de mi servidor web estaba mal, se supone que resuelve a la `192.168.1.2` y yo la tenía apuntando a `192.168.1.3`, entonces al momento de querer resolverse así mismo y eso lo comprobé haciendo un `wget` a la ip de mi servidor o a cualquier dominio dentro de él. Haciendo estos ajustes, el problema dejó de presentarse y mi servidor y cualquier tipo de petición que haga, sea `file_get_contents` or `curl` funcionan con normalidad.

Saludos.